# Software to change file creation/modified date in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, file-attributes

Is there any software that lets me change file attributes like creation/modify date of a file in Windows? If there are multiple, then which one is the best?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying the timestamp from one file to another (using PowerShell 2.0 on Windows-7)](http://superuser.com/questions/491980/copying-the-timestamp-from-one-file-to-another-using-powershell-2-0-on-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is freeware, and will change what you need plus various attributes that users don't normally have access to:

Attribute Changer
  http://www.petges.lu/

[image]